# Set popup message in Master Page and show them in other pages code behind ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have searched a lot on internet but failed to find the best solution. What I want is, to create popup messages in my master page and show them in child pages through code behind. 
Can somebody please give me any solution or suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add script in your `Master Page` and use a common class to use it.

If you are using bootstrap then `modal box` will work everywhere you need it.

And if you are using any other plugin for `popup` then, you nust add the script in your `master page`, so that it would available in your child pages too.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best way is to write custom user controls.

Take a look at this video from ASP.NET Web Site:
[[How Do I:] Create a Custom User Control in ASP.NET?](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-custom-user-control-in-aspnet)

*In other to help others, don't forget to mark as answer if this helps you.